# Passing multiple parameters from angular to rest service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am trying to pass the data to my rest services through $http.get() using URL.There are 10-12 parameters which I need to pass.

Angular script.js

```
$http.get('rest/test/getAllData/?filter1='$scope.filter1 + 
           '&filter2='$scope.filter2 + '&filter3='$scope.filter3 + 
           '&filter4='$scope.filter4)
```

The scope variables would come as undefined sometimes.But I guess that will not be a problem.I checked the console, the URL is getting formed correctly with all 12-13 parameters.

Now I am trying to get this in rest service using @QueryParam like below  -

```
@path("/getAllData")
@GET
@Produces({..}
public response getAllData(@QueryParam("filter1") final String filter1,
                           @QueryParam("filter2") final String filter2,
                           @QueryParam("filter3") final String filter3){
}
```

The problem is that the @QueryParam is working for 2 parameters but when I am increasing the number of parameters, it is failing. As per the browser console, I am getting **404 error**.

Is there any limitation to the number of parameters we can pass? I need to pass 12-13 parameters.How can I achieve this?

**Update -**

I was able to resolve my issue . I was using Date datatype in @QueryParam because of which it was throwing 404 error . Changed it to String and it worked . Did not know that we cannot use Date in QueryParam .

Apologies for not putting the detailed problem .

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but you can pass an object of params as the 2nd param to `$http.get` instead of building up the URL yourself: `$http.get('rest/test/getAllData/', { filter1: $scope.filter1, filter2: $scope.filter2, filter3: $scope.filter3, filter4: $scope.filter4 })`

Comment: I tried with params object , but somehow it is not working :(

Comment: I think your path should be like this `@path("/getAllData/")`

Comment: The call is going to the method . That is not a problem

Comment: Just a comment on your URL creation. What you show is the way many people will do it, but that is a brittle construction technique. I recommend using a dedicated URL builder service which will offload the responsibility of correct syntactic construction as well as proper escaping of data values. I provide just such a URL builder in my article [Code Smells: Raw Strings and the Subtle Syntax Catastrophe](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-development/code-smells-raw-strings-subtle-syntax-catastrophe/) on Simple-Talk.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the proper RESTful way then you can try like this, I have given it for couple of variables, but you can do for any.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/rest/test/getAllData/{filter1}/{filter2}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Data getAllData(@PathVariable String filter1, @PathVariable String filter2) {
  // code here
}
```

You can also achieve it using RequestParam, an example below, ensure your parameters matches

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/rest/test/getAllData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Data getAllData(@RequestParam String filter1, @RequestParam String filter2) {
// code here
```

}

If you still have a complicated structure then send it as a POST with the JSON data in the request body

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/rest/test/getAllData", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public Book getAllData(@RequestBody ObjectKey objectKey) {
// code here
```

}

Comment: OP not mention that ueses Spring MVC

Comment: I am not using spring MVC .Also If the values of filters are undefined or null .Will it not create a problem in requestMapping path ??

Comment: Better define the variables with a default value. So you dont have to worry about the undefined or empty. If it is undefined, it might even fail in your JS

Comment: Why not you use the POST method instead of GET? usually if we are send multiple request parameters then we use POST...

Comment: @themaster When you say it works with 2 parameters, do you mean you got a response from the API. Did you have 2 parameters in the REST API as well ?

Comment: @CrazyMac The call itself is not going .It is failing in JS side itself when adding more than 2 parameters .Throwing 404 error

Comment: @themaster What is happening when you just add 2 parameters? Do you get a success response ?

Answer (score 0):

For passing more number of parameters, you can use Rest parameter. It is used to access indefinite number of arguments passed to a function.

Syntax :

> `function add (...numbers){}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('paramName1', value1)
  .set('paramNmae2', value2);
   return this.httpClient.get<IMyObject[]>(this.myUrl, {params} ).pipe(
        tap(data=>console.log('ALL:'+JSON.stringify(data))),
    catchError(this.handleError));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.